# Passing JSON array to cloud function node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to convert a javascript object array to JSON to pass it with the POST request to the cloud function. However when I use the JSON.parse() function I get an error:SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, this is my POST request:

```
 const body = `{
                "item":[
                  {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
                  {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
                  {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}]
                }`;
                
                const init = {
                  method: 'POST',
                  body
                };
                
                fetch('https://us-central1-web-app-bbo-prod.cloudfunctions.net/TestObject', init)
                .then((response) => {
                  return response.json(); // or .text() or .blob() ...
                })
                .then((text) => {
                  // text is the response body
                })
                .catch((e) => {
                  // error in e.message
                });
```

and this my cloud function:

```
exports.TestObject = functions.https.onRequest(async(request, response)=> {
  var corsFn = cors();
  corsFn(request, response, async function() {


    const myJSON = request.body.item;



      console.log(JSON.parse(myJSON))


    //console.log(item)

  })})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:**

- Server: remove `JSON.parse`
- Client: change `init` to

```
const init = {
  method:'POST',
  body:JSON.stringify(body),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
  }
}
```

**Explained:**

You've got three issues I see.

Anytime you see the following you are calling JSON.parse on invalid stringified JSON.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
```

First, `req.body` should already be JSON if everything's working properly and you received JSON. To call `JSON.parse(req.body.item)` is to pass an Object to a function that takes strings. You can just refer to `req.body.item`.

Second you have to make sure you're sending the correct body, you are passing an object as the body for the fetch function. I'm not familiar with the fetch function but a quick look at the [Mozilla examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) indicate that should it should be stringified, i.e. `body:JSON.stringify(body)`. The object you pass likely is either converted to form data or has `toString()` called on it and you're sending `[object Object]`.

```
// REPL
> ({foo:'bar'}).toString()
'[object Object]'
```

Third, you have to make sure it gets parsed properly on the backend.

According to the [GCloud nodeJS docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/first-nodejs) the nodejs google cloud functions implement an endpoint for an [Express Router](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.use).

Normally if you wanted to use JSON the way you are you would need the body parser [BodyParser](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html) middleware. The examples here ([GCloud HTTP Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-http-form-data#functions_http_form_data-nodejs)) indicate that the body-parser middleware is already instead and working based off of Content-Type header.

Since it's deciding whether to parse it as JSON based on content type you want to set the header in your fetch function as `'content-type':'application/json'`.